# Getting undefined for findBy

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, undefined, findby

Ember **findBy** method is returning **undefined**, i'm new to ember and not able to figure out what am i doing wrong. I see that **user** and **account** data is present in store when viewed through Ember Inspector. Using the 2.7.0 version of ember and ember data.

```
this.get('store').findRecord('user', userId,{'include': 'accounts'}).then((user) => {
      this.set('currentUser', user);
      return user.get('accounts');
    }).then((accounts) =>{
      this.set('allAccounts', accounts);
      let account = accounts.findBy('primary');
      this.set('currentAccount',account);
      resolve();
    }).catch((error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
```

Comment: And you have verified in the debugger that one of the accounts has the `primary` property set to `true`?

Comment: yes i can verify that its present.

Comment: I think you'll need to add  a screenshot what `accounts` look like.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this?

`accounts.findBy('primary', true);`

Answer (score 0):

When `accounts` does not contain any object with the property `primary` undefined will be returned.